# Agree to Terms be for continuing

Tags: java, html

I am trying to set up a "Agree to Terms" checkbox and if checked I want the user to be redirected to another page on my site but I can only get it to make sure the checbox is checked or the buttons redirect but I can't seem to make it do both

My HTML:

```
<form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="checkbox" value="agree" required /><span style="color: #fff;">I agree to the </span><a href="tos.html" target="_blank">Terms of Services</a>
            <br>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="flex-item">

                    <p align="right"><input type="submit" id="mBY" class="myButtonY" name="submit" value="Continue as a&#13;&#10;Modder"></p>

                    <script>
                    if (checkbox.Checked == true) {
                        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("");
                        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

                    }

                    </script>

                </div>
                <div class="flex-item">

                    <p align="left"><input type="submit" class="myButtonN" name="submit" value="Continue as a&#13;&#10;Non-Modder"></p>

                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
```

I want the users to have to check the checkbox before they can continue and click the buttons and then depending on which button they click I want them to be redirected to a certain page on my site

Comment: Are you writing java in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `onclick` event to the `button`:

```
<button onclick="fun(this.value);" id="myButton1" value="Home">Home</button>

<button onclick="fun(this.value);" id="myButton2" value="Back">Back</button>
```

You could use `window.location` to redirect the user to the corresponding JSP pages.In `fun()` function write

```
function fun(str)
{
    if (checkbox.Checked == true) 
    {
        if(str=='Home')
        window.location = '/Home.jsp';

        if(str=='Back')
        window.location = '/Back.jsp';
    }
}
```

Comment: it does the same exact thing as I had before, my buttons will redirect still even if users do not click the agree to terms and if I remove the redirect it then asks users to click the checkbox